# Can't create snapshot agent for SQL Server 2016 publication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, merge-replication

Just installed a SQL Server 2016 instance fresh. Previously I've used merge replication for 2008 and 2012 without issues. I'm trying to do the same here, and while I can create the publication no problem, I get the following error when I try to create the snapshot agent. The SQL Server Agent is running, I can't find anything on the error online:

> > ===================================
>
> Cannot save changes to agent security settings.
>
> ===================================
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationObject.ExecCommand(String
>   commandIn)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Publication.CreateSnapshotAgent()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PageCreatePubAgentSecurity.SaveAgentSecurity(ReplAgentType
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubPropAgentSecurity.SaveProperties(ExecutionMode&
>   executionResult)
>
> ===================================
>
> Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_MSaddreplsymmetrickey'.
>   Changed database context to 'CoBRAClientData'. (.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.1601&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2812&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Server Name: SERVER1\COBRASERVER Error Number: 2812 Severity: 16 State: 62 Procedure:
>   sp_MSreplopensymmetrickey Line Number: 37
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction
>   action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean
>   catchException)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)

this happens through both sql management studio, and if i use the script:

```
exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'CoBRAClientPub', @frequency_type = 4, @frequency_interval = 14, @frequency_relative_interval = 1, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 1, @frequency_subday_interval = 5, @active_start_time_of_day = 500, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0, @job_login = N'server1\repl_snapshot', @job_password = null, @publisher_security_mode = 1
```

Comment: Could you please add the SQL query you are running to create snapshot agent?

Comment: I'm not running a sql query directly.  i'm using sql management studio.  right click the publication/properties/agent Security.  Click on 'create agent'

Comment: ah, but if i use a script,i get the same error.  see update

Comment: I haven't worked with this functionality, but the text of error say `Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_MSaddreplsymmetrickey'.` I've searched my SQL Server 2014 and haven't find this SP. May be it would be a solution if you try to create it. The source code of this SP could be found [here](http://www.g-productions.nl/index.php?name=sp_MSaddreplsymmetrickey)

Comment: there's a couple problems with that.  first, it doesn't like the TRIPLE_DES call in the stored proc.  if i change it to AES_256, then it passes, but it gives me an error that i can't create a 'sys' procedure.  if i change it from sys.sp_MSaddreplsymmetrickey to [sys.sp_MSaddreplsymmetrickey], that passes the error, but then i still get the original issue at the top about not finding the stored proc

Comment: Ah, `sys` schema, right. Forgot about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out a way around this using sql 2016.  Uninstalled, and installed sql 2014 (most recent service pack) and everything worked fine.  I had originally tried uinstalling 2016 and installing it back again, but that didn't work.  only 2014 did.